# How to calculate the fastest change in value over time for all points in a set of data?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a list of data with the data represented as a tuple `(Value, Time)`. For all of the data in my set I would like to calculate where the fastest rate of change occurs between any two given points in the set, not just points directly next to each other.

Examples:

Here the fastest change occurs between the 3rd and 4th points

```
(1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (Value changes by 1 unit in 1 step)
```

Here the fastest change occurs between the 4th and 5th points

```
(1.1, 1) (1.2, 2) (1.3, 3) (1.4, 4) (1.6, 5)
```

hmmm.. I can't seem to write an example where points not adjacent to each other change faster than points that are adjacent to each other. Can that happen? Ex. Where the 1st and last points change faster than the points between them.

I guess my question now is, do I need to worry about points that are not adjacent when finding the fastest change between two points?

EDIT: Values range from -12 to 12 and can be any value at anytime (within that range). The time between points is constant (or close enough that it doesn't matter).

Comment: The short answer is you must compare every pair of points.  This will require $n^2$ tests for $n$ points.  Is this a particular data set?  There is no way to design any heuristics (smart ways of choosing which subsets you must look at) without knowing anything about the dataset.  In your examples, the values are strictly increasing... is this true of your dataset?

Comment: But I don't think it is possible for two points that are not adjacent to change faster than two points that are. i.e. The fastest change can only happen between two adjacent data points. Its like saying the average between two non-adjacent data points is higher than the max of the data in that range, which is impossible?

Comment: Yes, that may be true, if your time step is constant and your values only increase.  Is that the case for your particular dataset?

Comment: The timestep is constant and the data can range from -12 to 12. // I guess, can you write out 5 points that have two non-adjacent points change faster than any two points between them? I can't think of one..

Comment: Oh right, this is a very good question.  I see what you mean.  I'll try!

Comment: Yes, I was certainly wrong about this.  You only need to compare adjacent pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a greater rate of change between two separated points than between one of the neighboring pairs.  Let the values be $a,b,c$.  The overall rate of change is $\frac 12(c-a)$, while the neighboring rates of change are $b-a$ and $c-b$.  But $\frac 12(c-a)=\frac 12[(c-b)+(b-a)]$, which will be less than one of $c-b$ or $b-a$ unless they are equal.